# How to interpret corollary

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I've just proved that if $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space and $T$ a linear map on $V$ with characteristic polynomial expressible as a product of linear factors, that there is a basis for $V$ w.r.t. which the matrix for $T$ is upper triangular.

There is a Corollary: If $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix with a characteristic polynomial that is a product of linear factors, then there is an $(n \times n)$-matrix $P$ such that $P^{−1}AP$ is upper triangular.

**My Question:** How do I fully, explicitly, spell out this corollary? I want to understand where the invertible $P$ comes from.

I started by saying: Consider the linear map $T$ given by $T(v)=Av$ but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix an ordered basis $\mathscr{B}_1$ for $V$. $A$, interpreted with this basis, represents a linear operator $T:V\to V$.

As the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is a product of linear factors, we know the same is true for $T$. Notice the characteristic polynomial is invariant under a change of basis, so this is all well-defined.

By the main theorem, there exists an ordered basis $\mathscr{B}_2$ in which the matrix representation of $T$ is an upper triangular matrix, $M$.

You should be aware that there is an invertible matrix $P$ which maps $\mathscr{B}_2$ to $\mathscr{B}_1$, in an order preserving way.

Then, $M=P^{-1}AP$ will hold - if you don't already know that, then it's a good idea to check this.

Similarly, you can use the result for matrices to get the result for operators.